# Child Theme Changes Are Not Reflecting In Parent Theme

Tags: plugins, themes, css

So I've recently moved my Wordpress.com blog to Wordpress.org.  I was using a Child theme via a Plugin and changed a bunch of the CSS, but when looking at the parent theme, nothing ever changed.  No changes I made in the Child theme reflected at all in the parent theme.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the parent theme and basically starting all over, but I still got the same result.  Here's my site:

http://thefigmentist.com

Maybe I just don't undertsand Child/Parent themes well enough.  Help?  Please?

Answer (score 0):

Generally for creating child theme you must use like this for example if you want to create a child theme for twentytwelve theme. First you want to make a copy of the twentytwelve theme and paste in same theme section and rename the copied folder into some other name you want in here I named as theme1child in this theme1child you should delete the functions.php and style.css file first.

After create a new style.css and function.php file in the style.css you have to call the parent theme like this

```
/*
Theme Name: theme1child 
Author: Your name
Author URI: 
Template:twentytwelve 
*/

@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");
```

You have to write like this in this template have the parent theme name is twentytwelve and you have to import the parent style.css file like this mentioned above. This is how you will create a child theme for an parent theme. Any doubts regarding this let me know